# How do I write a sockproxy in Perl?

Tags: proxy, torsocks

You may have seen my other question related to piping a Perl script designed to connect to a webpage through Tor. I've decided that this was too much of a hassle and I now need a short tutorial on how to build a proxy in a Perl script that will allow me to connect to hidden services and  (later) download files from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LWP::UserAgent can it, if LWP::Protocol::socks and Tor are installed. [LWP::Protocol::socks](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Protocol::socks) is available as *liblwp-protocol-socks-perl* software package at least in the repositories of [Debian](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=names&keywords=liblwp-protocol-socks-perl) and [Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=liblwp-protocol-socks-perl); when LWP::Protocol::socks is already installed, you can forget its name and just call LWP::UserAgent.

I had a similar question a week ago, and I written the script *testtor.perl*:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $url;
if ($ARGV[0]) {
 $url = $ARGV[0];
}
else {
 exit;
}

my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent(agent => 'perl');
$ua -> proxy([qw(http https)] => 'socks://127.0.0.1:9050');
my $response = $ua -> get($url);
my $page = $response -> decoded_content;
print "$page\n";
```

It is not a CGI script; so, it does not print HTTP headers. It is for calling it from another script or terminal. E.g., the line in terminal

```
./testtor.perl https://www.iplocation.net/find-ip-address | lynx -stdin
```

will open in Lynx a page with an IP address of some Tor exit relay. And

```
./testtor.perl http://podger42hd4zi2oc.onion/ | lynx -stdin
```

works, too.

Comment: Thank you! Your code didn't originally work, but I made some modifications and it now works :) Now I need to pick a hidden service to try it with....

Comment: Is there a way to find specific files on the server, not just the mainpage?

Comment: @NoName, what line in my script was not working at your computer? Have you installed LWP::Protocol::socks and Tor? About your question, have you tried _locate_?

Comment: @NoName, I am sorry to say it, but it looks like you have read my answer inattentively. The script, as I written it, needs one command line argument (when a Perl programme is called with arguments, they all are available as the `@ARGV` array; e.g., if you called `/path/to/script foo bar` then $ARGV[0] = 'foo' and $ARGV[1] = 'bar'). If you call `./testtor.perl https://check.torproject.org/ | lynx -stdin` (just using my script in its original form), you will see "Congratulations. This browser is configured to use Tor" etc.

Comment: I apologize for that. I'm new to code, and I suppose I don't have enough insight yet to arbitrarily criticize code errors. To clarify, the original intent of the question was not to use the browser, but simply use CLI to fetch pages. We may have misunderstood each other :)

Answer (score 0):

You need *IO::Socket::Socks* module. It can be used as SOCKS5 client, point it to running tor as socks server. Usually runs on ports 9050 or 9150.

Comment: Thank you- I'm busy right now but will be sure to test this later!

Comment: I followed CPAN's instructions to the letter on making a proxy using this module. Perl returned messages pertaining to errors in the module's code.